# Regular Expression with Masked Textbox Issue

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, maskedtextbox

Im trying to prepare a phone number textbox but I couldn't find a way to make it work properly. I don't want javascript or jquery...

I want it to have the mask structure: (0312) 255 29 47

User can't leave it blank so I put the required field validator and I wanna validate this with regular expression for proper format.

This is my code below. Thanks for any help

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTelefon" runat="server" ValidationGroup="contact" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" TargetControlID="txtTelefon" MaskType="Number" Mask="(999) 999 99 99" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionPhone"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtTelefon"
            Display="Dynamic"
            ErrorMessage="Invalid phone number"
            SetFocusOnError="True"
            ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{2}-\d{2}">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"  ErorMessage="Please enter a valid phone number!" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtTelefon" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: What validation are you looking for? `1234567890` or `(123) 4567890` or `123 456-78-90` or `12345678 90` something like a mix of them all ?

Comment: my validation expession is ok, the problem is that they are not working properly. for example if i dont put a value and it doesnt give required field alert.

Comment: You're not giving enough information, that's why you get no answers to this _extremely_ simple regex. The regex you provide does not validate anything but disjointed numbers space and dashes. You need to give info about partial/complete and form of the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example `(0312) 255 29 47`, a valid regex to match it would be:

```
\(\d{4}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}
```

See https://www.regex101.com/r/bA3aY1/1 for a detailed explanation about the regex.

Comment: still its not compatible with my mask it gives invalid phone number error

Comment: I want it works with mask, so when user opened the page he will see a mask like that (0___) ___ __ __ and he will fill it with only numbers. as you see first number is always 0.